# Bucket selector using _count to remove empty buckets not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm attempting to remove empty buckets from my aggregation results. I've tried using the bucket selector in various parts of the query, but I'm still getting empty buckets in the response. Can someone suggest a solution to remove these empty buckets from my aggregation results?

this is my query

```
POST newlogincloud*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Microser": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "service.name.keyword",
        "size": 15,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Errores": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "transaction.detail.status_code",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 30
          },
          "aggs": {
            "selector2": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "buckets": "_count"
                },
                "script": "params.buckets > 1"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "buckets": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.buckets > 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-6h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my response

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "Microser": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "service-A",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "Errores": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "service-E",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "Errores": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "service-B",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "Errores": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```